# Combinatorial Optimization of a function of a matrix

Tags: combinatorial-optimization

We have a $N\times M$ matrix $H$. We choose $n$ rows of this matrix and form a new matrix $G$. Then we form the following matrices.

$S = GP^\prime G^T+R$

$K = P^\prime G^TS^{-1}$

$P = P^\prime - KSK^T$

where $P^\prime$ is a symmetric positive-definite matrix and $R$ is diagonal matrix with positive entries. The goal is to choose those $n$ rows in a way to minimize the following function

$f(P) = trace(P)$

It can be proved that $f$ is not sensitive to the order in which we choose the rows and form matrix $G$. Also, assume that $N$ is large and we can not do brute-force checking.

Comment: As asked, this question is far too vague; we know next-to-nothing about the function $f$.

Comment: use brute force, Luke! try each subset of H rows and find min

Comment: Is $P'$ fixed? If so, then $\text{tr}(P) = \text{tr}(P') - \text{tr}(KSK^t)$, so we can just look at $\text{tr}(KSK^t)$.

Comment: Yes, $P^\prime$ is fixed

Answer (score 0):

If the function's value doesn't depend on the order of the rows, it can still depend on the order of the entries within a row.

Because of the symmetry of $f$ w.r.t. rows the following heuristic might be applicable:
evaluate $f$ for $N1$ copies of a single row; that yields a ranking of the individual rows.

The heuristic solution is then to choose as $H1$ a composition of the $N1$ top-ranked rows.

Comment: Why should this heuristic provide a better answer than random guessing? I think you are making an unwarranted (according to the question) or hidden assumption about $f$ here.

Comment: @user44191 could you please be more specific about which assumption is invalid or provide a counterexample?

Comment: Counterexample 1: $N_1 = M, f(H_1) = |det(H_1)|$. When you take $N_1$ copies of each row, you get $0$ - so this heuristic gives no information at all. Counterexample 2: $M = 3, N = 3$ with the identity matrix, $N_1 = 2, f(x, y, z) = x_1 x_2 + 10000 y_1z_2 + 10000 y_2z_1$.

Comment: @user44191 ok, agreed; maybe I was too conditioned by [Blossoming and Polar Forms](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwjxkdywpdvgAhUJr6QKHRwZD1IQFjADegQIBhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresources.mpi-inf.mpg.de%2Fdepartments%2Fd4%2Fteaching%2Fss2010%2Fgeomod%2Fslides_public%2F08_Blossoming_Polars.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3A2_buLZsVqXAoP0k7wKgK).